# Issue accessing S3 from Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-s3

With the following config.

```
os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'xxxxxx'
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'xxxxxxxx'
os.environ['AWS_REGION'] = 'us-west-2'
os.environ['S3_ENDPOINT'] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
os.environ['S3_USE_HTTPS'] = '1'                          
os.environ['S3_VERIFY_SSL'] = '1' 

print(file_io.stat('s3://abcd/def.txt'))
```

I get the error

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py in stat(filename)
>       556   with errors.raise_exception_on_not_ok_status() as status:
>       557     pywrap_tensorflow.Stat(compat.as_bytes(filename), file_statistics, status)
>   --> 558     return file_statistics
>       559 
>       560
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
>       526             None, None,
>       527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
>   --> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>       529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
>       530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to
>
> NotFoundError: Object s3://abcd/def.txt does not exist

Note this file does exist.

I also get the following error on a write and close.

> UnknownError: PermanentRedirect: Unable to parse ExceptionName: PermanentRedirect Message: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

What more is needed to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is how my config looks like:

```
import os
os.environ['AWS_REGION'] = 'us-west-2'
os.environ['S3_ENDPOINT'] = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
os.environ['S3_VERIFY_SSL'] = '0'
```

I think you have to change from

```
os.environ['S3_ENDPOINT'] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

to

```
os.environ['S3_ENDPOINT'] = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

Here is [a link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38054) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can use endpoint like 
 mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

then use s3://pathtofile to access